# QML - Switch button is controlled by spacebar - why?

Tags: python, pyqt, qml, pyside

In my Pyside/QML application I want to use *spacebar* `onPressed` event for my purpose - it works. When add to my app *Switch button*, then the *spacebar button* controls the **Switch** instead of calling my `onPressed` event.
Is there any way to disable the **Switch** from being controlled by the spacebar button?

1. Spacebar catch event:

```
Item {
        anchors.fill: parent
        focus: true
        Keys.onPressed: (event)=> {
            
                if (event.key == Qt.Key_Space) {
                    backend.btnStartFlash();
                    event.accepted = true;
                }
            }
        }
```

2. Switch button

```
 Switch {
                    id: switchBtn
                    text: qsTr("mode")
                    font.pixelSize: 16
                    font.bold: false
                    font.italic: true
                    checked:false
}
```

Comment: This can be done python, I am not sure about qml though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by the `focus` property of the `Switch`. When you click it, it takes over the focus. Either you set the `focus` property of the `Switch` to `false` and the `focus` of the `Item`to `true` at some point to get back the focus on the `Item` or you don't allow the `Switch` to never get focus with the `focusPolicy` property ([focusPolicy documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-controls2-control.html#focusPolicy-prop)).

One remark: You should use `===` for comparison in JavaScript. You could also use the `Keys.onSpacePressed` directly to avoid the if statement ([spacePressed documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-keys.html#spacePressed-signal)).

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Item {
        anchors.fill: parent
        focus: true
        Keys.onSpacePressed: (event)=> {
            console.log("Space pressed")
            event.accepted = true
        }
    }

     Switch {
        id: switchBtn
        text: qsTr("mode")
        font.pixelSize: 16
        font.bold: false
        font.italic: true
        checked: false
        focusPolicy: Qt.NoFocus
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to send the space events from the Switch back to the Item as follows:

```
    Item {
        id: thisItem
        anchors.fill: parent
        focus: true
        Keys.onPressed: (event) => {
            if (event.key == Qt.Key_Space) {
                backend.btnStartFlash();
                event.accepted = true;
            }
        }
    }

    // ...

    Switch {
        id: switchBtn
        text: qsTr("mode")
        font.pixelSize: 16
        font.bold: false
        font.italic: true
        checked:false
        Keys.onPressed: (event) => {
            if (event.key == Qt.Key_Space) {
                thisItem.forceActiveFocus();
            }
        }
    }
```